# What is the meaning of `~` in python grammar

Tags: python, parsing, cpython, ebnf, peg

I was going through the [python grammer specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html#full-grammar-specification) and find the following statement

```
for_stmt:
    | 'for' star_targets 'in' ~ star_expressions ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] block [else_block]
```

What does `~` means in this grammar rule?. The other symbols used in the grammer(like `&`, `!`, `|`) are already documented but not `~`.

> The notation is a mixture of `EBNF` and `PEG`. In particular, `&` followed
> by a symbol, token or parenthesized group indicates a positive
> lookahead (i.e., is required to match but not consumed), while `!`
> indicates a negative lookahead (i.e., is required *not* to match). We
> use the `|` separator to mean PEG’s “ordered choice” (written as `/` in
> traditional PEG grammars)

Comment: @buran This is a question about EBNF/PEG, not Python syntax.

Comment: @theberzi, my bad

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's documented in [PEP 617](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0617/) under Grammar Expressions:

> ~
>
> Commit to the current alternative, even if it fails to parse.
>
> `rule_name: '(' ~ some_rule ')' | some_alt`
>
> In this example, if a left parenthesis is parsed, then the other alternative won’t be considered, even if some_rule or ‘)’ fail to be parsed.

The `~` basically indicates that once you reach it, you're locked into the particular rule and cannot move onto the next rule if the parse fails.
PEP 617 mentions earlier that `| some_alt` can be written in the next line.